# Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 80) MAP must be a m x 3 array. Error in rgb2gray (line 52) isRGB = parse_inputs(X);

Tags: matlab

I don't know where the problem is and how to solve it in my program:

```
        Img = app.Property.Img;
        gray = rgb2gray(Img);
        
        imshow(gray,'Parent',app.UIAxes_2)
        title(app.UIAxes_2,'Citra Grayscale')
        
        app.Property.gray = gray;
```

please help in this case I've tried it still doesn't work :(

Comment: `Img` must be a *m*-by-*n*-by-3 array. It is not. I suggest you either print out `size(Img)` or look at the variable in the debugger.